# NodeJs API msrestazure proxy issue

Tags: node.js, api, proxy

I've a nodejs api that uses npm package `msrestazure`.
From my local development I've to pass via enterprise proxy to get to the internet.

When I try `msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret` I get a connection timeout due to the fact that request doesn't use the proxy.

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.143.136.20:443

If someone knows how I can force the usage of the proxy tell me.

---

For info i've tested multiple solution

- set proxy environment variable : not running
- use netsh winhttp to set proxy : not running
- use software proxycap : it runs. But software is not free and can't request to other developper to use it.

Any has an idea ?? Issue is only for request done by the package.
If i use http request to do the request my self, it works :(

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

sorry for delay ...

Solution is to use package npm dotenv and add HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variable in it.

Hope that can help :)